# What is the difference between a volume and a block regarding partitions in disk?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems

What I understood about volume is:

Partitioning means dividing the physical drive into several logical drives / volumes that the OS treats as completely separate physical drives. Each volume on a partitioned disk has a drive letter ( C,D,E ).

I read that each volume has a block.So blocks are inside volumes? What exactly is a block? Please explain in a simple way.

So example of a volume is the C drive. Then what would be the example of a block? Thank you!

Comment: Please delete or close your cross posted questions https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436552/what-is-the-difference-between-a-volume-and-a-block-regarding-partitions-on-a-di

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/90461/755, https://superuser.com/q/1312375/93541, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/436552/9812.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend, my friend. These are very simple descriptions of these two aspects of data storage.

### Volumes

[from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_(computing)):

> In computer data storage, a volume or logical drive is a single
>   accessible storage area with a single file system, typically (though
>   not necessarily) resident on a single partition of a hard disk.

### Blocks

[from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)):

> In computing (specifically data transmission and data storage), a
>   block, sometimes called a physical record, is a sequence of bytes or
>   bits, usually containing some whole number of records, having a
>   maximum length, a block size.

Comment: So there is a disk which is partitioned into volumes. Each volume has data arranged in them and this arrangement is called blocks right? Blocks are groups of data in volumes. Am I right?

Comment: No, a Block is a sequence of bits or bytes. There is no requirement that information be written to a block, therefore the use of the word "data" is unnecessary.

Comment: So basically volumes contain blocks. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but that is only one of their characteristics, and I am not certain I can say for a fact that a data-storage volume MUST contain blocks.

Comment: If this answers your question please click the Checkmark icon next to the question to indicate it is the answer.